# Why does my form_for area#new have a button that says "Update Area", not "Create Area"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an area model that belongs to a report model. I have built a form partial using SimpleForm. When I go to new_report_area_path(@report), I get a New Area form that works just fine. Enter the details and hit submit and it creates an area and takes you to area#show. But the button on the new area form says "Update Area" not "Create Area". Why?

**config/routes.rb:**

```
Testivate::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :reports do
    resources :areas
  end
end
```

**db/schema.rb:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121205045544) do
  create_table "areas", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "report_id"
  end
  create_table "reports", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
end
```

**app/models/area.rb:**

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :heuristics
  belongs_to :report
end
```

**app/models/report.rb:**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :heuristics
  has_many :areas
end
```

**app/controllers/areas_controller.rb:**

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController  
  filter_resource_access
  def new
    @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
    @area = @report.areas.create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end
  def create
    @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
    @area = @report.areas.create(params[:area])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @area.save
        format.html { redirect_to report_area_path(@report, @area), notice: 'Area was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/areas/news.html.haml:**

```
%h1 New Area
= render 'form'
```

**app/views/areas/_form.html.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for [@report, @area] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an area you should building it as it's a new action:

```
def new
  @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
  @area = @report.areas.build # build instead of create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
  end
end
```